# Почему в WebStorm все подчеркивает и не работают подсказки в js в файле, а в CSS и HTML работают

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему в WebStorm все подчеркивает и не работают подсказки в js в файле, а в CSS и HTML работают